# Read an object from the file

Tags: c++, file

I am making a record of cars using a matrix of pointers from a class of Transport and store it with a file, I enter a special number for a particular car and store it in a file called "type" and store the object in a file called "TransportFilePath" but when I read it reads only the special number without the object

```
 void ProgrammeManagement:: Transport_ Building_Record()
    {
        int x,id,engine_Number,door_Number,num;
        char an;
        double length,speed;
        string transport_Name,company,property_Type,transport_Type;
        tm date;
        static int i = 0;
        fstream file(TransportFilePath,ios::out|ios::binary|ios::trunc);
        fstream filee(Type,ios::out|ios::binary);
        cout << "how many Cars"<<endl;
        cin >> x;
        Transport **T = new Transport *[x];
        do
        {
            cout << "Special number: ";
            cin >> num;
            cin >> id;
            cin >> transport_Name;
            cin >> company; 
            cin >> date.tm_yday >> date.tm_mon >> date.tm_year;
            cin >> speed;
            cin >> transport_Type;
            cin >> property_Type;
            cin >> engine_Number;
            cin >> length;
            cin >> door_Number;
            T[i] = new Car(id,transport_Name,company,date,speed,property_Type,transport_Type,engine_Number,length,door_Number);
            filee.write((char*)&num,sizeof(int));
            file.write((char*)&T[i],sizeof(Transport));
            i++;
            cout << "enter Y input Car";
            cin >> an;
        }
        while ( i <x && an == 'Y');
        file.close();
        filee.close();
    }
```

But when I want to read from the file, nothing prints on the console screen .

```
void ProgrammeManagement::read()
{
    int n;
    Car z;
    fstream fil(Type,ios::in|ios::binary);
    fstream filll(TransportFilePath,ios::in|ios::binary);
    while(fil.read((char*)&n,sizeof(int)))
    {
        cout << "number : "<<n<<endl;
        while(filll.read((char*)&z,sizeof(Car)))
            z.Print();
    }
    fil.close();
    filll.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `Car`? Would it make sense to be able to store such objects in raw binary forms in a file? Is `Car`  a [POD type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType)? Does it contain any pointers (or objects who might contain pointers)?

Comment: And `file.write((char*)&T[i],sizeof(Transport));` really doesn't make sense... Remember that `T` is an array of pointers, which means `T[i]` is of type `Transport*`, and `&T[i]` is of type `Transport**`. You write a pointer to the file, not a structure or object.

Comment: car is class and transport is abstract class ,I want to store car objects in a matrix and store them in a file